# SPI конфликтует с дисплеем

Tags: arduino, spi

Я решил организовать чтение информации с кард ридера и отрисовки её на телеке, который подключен через библиотеку TVout (Порты 8, 9, они задефайнены в заголовочнике библиотеки) но он не инициализируется, если отключить либу SD и весь связанный с ней код, то всё работает, также есть динамик на 7 порту, но он работает всегда. Мой код: https://codeshare.io/K8rPwK

Comment: p.s. Код не дописан до состояния вывода инфы с карточки

Comment: А железо какое? Как ТВ подключен? Без схемы и понимания какие компоненты задествованы вообще ничего не разобрать.